# How to do comments with javascript hilights?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my project i have these comments that runs javascript, in VSCode, is there any way to insert JS hilight in these comments?

[image: HTML comment]

[image: JS comment]

[image: CSS comment]

Comment: How does these comments work? Is it some kind of library?

Comment: write a new language extension and inject parts of it as JavaScript in the TextMate grammar

Comment: why post images of text, SO also will highlight it as a comment

Comment: [Embedded languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#embedded-languages) and [Injection grammars](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars)

Comment: @Konrad it is a html file but on the get route the comments starting with `ncf` gets js evaluated, a simple example is that: i have a node module containing my http routes, i can show the routes on the html file doing so: `<body><!-- ncf return require("./myRoutes").map(r=>r.path); --></body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Embedded languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#embedded-languages) was what i wanted.